# My program fails with ArrayIndexOutofBoundsExeption Error

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

Hello my program fails to run with `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsExeption`. I get this error when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -35
at RoulleteChecker.main(RoulleteChecker.java:134)
```

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class RoulleteChecker {

      public static void main( String args[] )
      {

          int a[] = new int[37];

          for ( long roll = 1; roll <=99999999; roll++ ) {      
             a[0] = 1 + ( int ) ( Math.random() * 34); 

             switch ( a[0] ) {

               case 0:
                  ++a[1];
                   break; 

                case 1:
                   ++a[2];
                  break;

                case 2:
                   ++a[3];
                   break;

                case 3:
                   ++a[4];
                   break;

                case 4:
                   ++a[5];
                   break;

                case 5:
                   ++a[6];
                   break;
                case 6:
                    ++a[7];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    ++a[8];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ++a[9];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    ++a[10];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    ++a[11];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    ++a[12];
                    break;
                case 12:
                    ++a[13];
                    break;
                case 13:
                    ++a[14];
                    break;
                case 14:
                    ++a[15];
                    break;
                case 15:
                    ++a[16];
                    break;
                case 16:
                    ++a[17];
                    break;
                case 17:
                    ++a[18];
                    break;
                case 18:
                    ++a[19];
                    break;
                case 19:
                    ++a[20];
                    break;
                case 20:
                    ++a[21];
                    break;
                case 21:
                    ++a[22];
                    break;
                case 22:
                    ++a[23];
                    break;
                case 23:
                    ++a[24];
                    break;
                case 24:
                    ++a[25];
                    break;
                case 25:
                    ++a[26];
                    break;
                case 26:
                    ++a[27];
                    break;
                case 27:
                    ++a[28];
                    break;
                case 28:
                    ++a[29];
                    break;
                case 29:
                    ++a[30];
                    break;
                case 30:
                    ++a[31];
                    break;
                case 31:
                    ++a[32];
                    break;
                case 32:
                    ++a[33];
                    break;
                case 33:
                    ++a[34];
                    break;
                case 34:
                    ++a[35];
                    break;
             } 

         } 

         JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();

         outputArea.setText( "Lets see: " + a[0-35] );

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, outputArea,
             "Searching for the frequency: 99999999 times", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );  
         System.exit( 1 );

     }  
}
```

Please my head is going to blow with this. I think that my error is on the `a` variable.

Comment: What do you think this `a[0-35]` does?

Comment: The huge switch block can be changed into 1-3 lines of code.

Comment: Print the content of the array by iterating over it. Remove that `a[0-35]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all that gigantic switch could be replaced by this:

```
++a[a[0] + 1];
```

Then, as other people already pointed out, `a[0 - 35]` do not means what you want, it will not magically grab the positions 0 to 35 of the array. It is just the math result of 0 subtracted to 35, which is -35. There is no position -35 on an array.

To represent the array as a String, we can use Java 8 Streams:

```
IntStream.of(a).limit(36).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).toString().replace(", ", "\n")
```

What this does:

1. This will convert the `int[]` to a `IntStream` (the `IntStream.of(a)` part).
2. Lets limit to get only the first 36 elements (since you wanted the elements from 0 to 35). This is what the `.limit(36)` does.
3. Then the `IntStream` will be converted to a `Stream<Integer>` (the `.boxed()`) part.
4. Then it will be converted to a `List<Integer>` (the `.collect(Collectors.toList())`) part.
5. Then it will be converted to a `String` (the `.toString()` part).
6. Since that `String` will be too long to be presented on a single line, it is a good idea to add some line breaks, this is what the `.replace(", ", "\n")` does.

Finally, you don't need the `System.exit(1);`, it has no purpose here.

With that, this is your resulting code:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class RoulleteChecker {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int a[] = new int[37];

        for (long roll = 1; roll <= 99999999; roll++) {
            a[0] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 34);
            ++a[a[0] + 1];
        }

        JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();

        outputArea.setText("Lets see: " + IntStream.of(a).limit(36).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).toString().replace(", ", "\n"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputArea,
                "Searching for the frequency: 99999999 times", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

---

## New improved answer:

To show line numbers, I think that the `Stream`s approach will not work or it would be overly complex. So lets use an specialized method instead:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class RoulleteChecker {

    private static final int TIMES = 99999999;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int a[] = new int[36];

        for (long roll = 1; roll <= TIMES; roll++) {
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * a.length);
            ++a[r];
        }

        JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();

        outputArea.setText("Lets see:\n" + asString(a));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputArea,
                "Searching for the frequency: " + TIMES + " times", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    private static String asString(int[] s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8 * s.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            sb.append(i + 1).append(": ").append(s[i]).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

There is a few more differences here:

- Since the 0th position of the array is just to temporarily hold the newly generated number, lets get it out of the array entirely. This is what the `r` variable is. And since I removed the 0th position of the array, so I removed the `+ 1` on the `++a[a[0] + 1]` which became simply `++a[r]`.
- I moved the number of times (99999999) to a constant. This makes it easier to make it changeable if needed.
- Again, since I removed the 0th position of the array, I also removed the `1 +` from the line that calculated a random number. Further, I made it grab the size of the array dynamically, so you don't need to track the array size both when creating it and when randomly accessing one of its positions.
- The `asString` method should be pretty easy straightforward. The only gotcha is the `i + 1`, where the `+ 1` has the purpose to show the indexes starting at 1 instead of 0.
- The parameter on the `StringBuilder`'s constructor in the `asString` method is just a total `String` size estimative for performance, it is not an important thing.

Comment: Can you tell me something else i want every line starts with a number. But i want this number will be different in the other lines like 1: \n 2: \n 3 etc from 0 to 34 can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The error is from this line:

```
outputArea.setText( "Lets see: " + a[0-35] );
```

The `-` sign is the arithmetic minus operator. So, 0 - 35 is `-35`, which is, of course, not a valid index. I'm guessing you wanted to print the **range** of 0 to 35, which could be done with [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])):

```
outputArea.setText( "Lets see: " + Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Java:

```
 a[0-35]
```

actually means:

```
 a[-35]
```

What makes you think -35 is a valid index? You see --- all the information that you need to fix the bug is there - you just have to read the exception message carefully. It tells you the position of the error, and it tells you the invalid index!

And btw: consider your switch statement.

Do you really think you need to write down a switch that more or less does

```
case i:
  i++;
```

?

Comment: Sorry, typo; I meant -35 (because of 0-35).

Comment: You are welcome - feel free to upvote the correct answers and accept one of them!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote :/. Anyway thank you again :)